# How to use FTP_TLS (Explicit mode) with urllib.request.urlopen() (or equivalent of `urlopen` with FTP_TLS)

Tags: python, urllib, ftplib

I'm using some older Python 3 code that works like this:

```py
import os
import json
import re
import csv
import urllib.request
import requests

url = "ftp://username:password@server/path-to-file.txt"

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    lines = [l.decode('latin-1') for l in response.readlines()]
    rows = csv.reader(lines, delimiter=';')
    return rows
except Exception as err:
    current_app.log.error('Error when trying to read URL and parse CSV: %s' % (url))
    raise
```

This has always worked fine, but recently the FTP server, which I don't have any control over, switched to explicit TLS. This results in an error trace like this:

```py
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1583, in ftp_open
    raise exc.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1565, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1586, in connect_ftp
    return ftpwrapper(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, timeout,
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 2407, in __init__
    self.init()
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 2417, in init
    self.ftp.login(self.user, self.passwd)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 412, in login
    resp = self.sendcmd('USER ' + user)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 281, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 254, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: error_perm('530 Not logged in.')>
```

The relevant part, I think, is that the `ftplib` library is now unable to log in with the `urllib` library.

For the sake of testing my ability to access the server at all, I tried using `FTP_TLS` like this:

```py
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftp = FTP_TLS()
ftp.context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')
ftp.connect('ftp.serverpath')
ftp.login('username','password')
ftp.close()
```

This works fine. The server reports that I'm logged in: `'230 User logged in, proceed.'` is the message.

So, the `urllib.request.urlopen()` functionality is really convenient for accessing the data I need later in the application, but the way it uses the `ftplib` now keeps me from logging in to the server. Using `FTP_TLS` works fine to access the server, but I'm not sure how to download the CSV once I'm logged in.

Is there a way I can either tell `urllib.request.urlopen()` to use `FTP_TLS`, or that I can do an equivalent to quickly open the file once I'm logged in with `ftplib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTPS support can be added to [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) by installing a new [`OpenerDirector`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.OpenerDirector) with a modified [`FTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.FTPHandler) subclass:

```py
import csv
import io
import urllib.request


class FTPSWrapper(urllib.request.ftpwrapper):
    """
    Like urllib.request.ftpwrapper, but enforces FTPS.
    """

    def init(self):
        # This code was copied and modified from the standard library.
        # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f14ced6062ecdd3c654f3c558f79e1edf4f10cc8/Lib/urllib/request.py#L2412-L2419
        import ftplib

        self.busy = 0
        # Specify FTPS here
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS()
        self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
        self.ftp.login(self.user, self.passwd)
        # Set up a secure data connection
        self.ftp.prot_p()
        _target = "/".join(self.dirs)
        self.ftp.cwd(_target)


class FTPSHandler(urllib.request.FTPHandler):
    """
    Like urllib.request.FTPHandler, but enforces FTPS.
    """

    def connect_ftp(self, *args):
        # Use the subclass we defined above.
        return FTPSWrapper(*args, persistent=False)


def download_ftp_file(url: str):
    """
    Given a URL to a file, download it, decode it using latin-1,
    and return a text stream of its contents.
    """
    urllib.request.install_opener(urllib.request.build_opener(FTPSHandler))
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return io.TextIOWrapper(response, encoding="latin-1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "ftp://username:password@server/path-to-file.txt"
    reader = csv.reader(download_ftp_file(url))
    print(list(reader))
```

The magic is the calls to [`build_opener`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.build_opener) and [`install_opener`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.install_opener), which allow us to add new URL handling logic to `urlopen`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was hoping might be possible!